# Using Gstreamer with pthreads

Tags: multithreading, pthreads, gstreamer

I've read most of the documentation about Gstreamer and how to use it, but there's very little explained about combining Gstreamer and other non
gstreamer-related threads.

So I'm trying to create a simple application where on one thread I have a simple pipeline with a source element connected directly to  a sink element. I'm using "pthread" library to manage the threads. Then I create another pthread to handle the other parts of the program.

To do this I'm using this example (http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/04/create-threads-in-linux/?utm_source=feedburner).

Here is the program:

```
#include<gst/gst.h>

#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>

pthread_t tid[2];

void* doSomeThing(void *arg)
{
    GMainLoop *loop;

    printf("\n Completed. \n");

    GstElement *pipeline;

    loop = g_main_loop_new (NULL, FALSE);

    pipeline = gst_parse_launch ("gst-launch v4l2src ! xvimagesink", NULL);

    gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

    g_main_loop_run (loop);

    gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);

    gst_object_unref (GST_OBJECT (pipeline));

    g_main_loop_unref (loop);

    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    gst_init (&argc, &argv);

    pthread_create(&(tid[0]), NULL, &doSomeThing, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

So I compile. No errors. When I run it, it doesn't open any windows and doesn't start streaming or anything. I have the feeling that's it's the way I'm creating my pipeline thread. So bottomline is I don't have a good knowledge of Gstreamer and any help is much appreciated.

(Notice that in the previous code I omitted the creation of the second thread since the problem is that the pipeline isn't streaming.)

Comment: I don't have a single iota of experience with pthreads or gstreamer, or how threads work on unix boxes, but I'll point out that your application runs straight through that main method and exits.  I'll wager pthreads are background threads and are killed as soon as the main thread terminates.  You've got to block that main method and wait until everything is completed.

Comment: Also there is no reason to have an extra thread for your GStreamer pipeline. GStreamer spawns its own threads internally and its API is non-blocking for the most part.

Comment: @Florian Zwoch.. Yes, I've tried running the pipeline all on the same thread, but it doesn't continue from there on. So as far as I know it's blocking. I see that I'm not getting any answer so either my question is really stupid and for the first time nobody knows the answer. At least can somebody point me in the direction of good documentation on combining Gstreamer with other non-Gstreamer related threads?

Comment: GStreamer runs in its own threads. That is probably why you have the Glib main loop in your code to have something running at all. Will's comment about the main() exiting immediately is right though. In that time GStreamer won't be able to do anything. I suggest reading some GStreamer samples before you consider tinkering with extra threads. Most likely you won't even need them.

Answer (score 0):

`g_main_loop_run()` is a GLib event loop: there is a loop inside (send a quit signal to it when you want to terminate it). That's it, anything else is not relevant to the thread interaction.

That's not correct:

`gst_parse_launch ("gst-launch v4l2src ! xvimagesink", NULL);`

Should probably be:

```
gst_parse_launch ("v4l2src ! xvimagesink", NULL);
```

Set `GST_DEBUG` environment variable to some level. Add checks and error handlers to the code (like listening on the bus of the pipeline and printing errors or checking that `gst_parse_launch(...) != NULL` and the state is really changed to "playing").

Comment: Yea the first thing you mentioned was not the problem since gst-parse-launch parses the command line command and "v4l2src ! xvimagesink" doesn't work. 

What did the trick was putting a sleep(5) or stoping the program from ending in the main() function, so thanks to Will that commented and helped.

What Florian Wzoch said is wrong though. I tried doing something after setting the pipeline to play and it didn't do it. So there might be ways to create and stream pipelines in a non-blocking way but the way I was doing it was definitely blocking it.

Comment: If its blocking it means that the pipeline is not pre-rolling. That means something else is not working with your pipeline. If the pipeline correctly changes its state to playing it will continue program execution.